# Can I hook up two monitors

Tags: windows-xp

I have a wacom interactive tablet for my editing.  I hook it up to my laptop to use Photoshop.  My question is can I hook up another monitor?  I want to hook up a larger monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you attached an additional monitor to your laptop then yes, you can. Obviously it depends on the age of the laptop and what connector you have. For example I have a Dell Inspiron 1520 and I can use the normal blue VGA connector you find on the end of most monitors. I plug it in, press a combination of keys and the display can be shown in a variety of configurations - one desktop on each screen, stretch the display across both etc.

Some modern day laptops have an HDMI connector instead of the VGA connector so you'll have to take a look and see what you have and buy the monitor that will work for you.